# Generating string from for loop causes memory overload on iOS

Tags: ios, for-loop, memory-management, nsstring, out-of-memory

so I'm facing a memory issue here.
I'm trying to generate a GPX string from an array of location objects.

I have this function that parses every object I have in an array, and adds information to the GPX string. My array can contain more than 1000 object, so the for loop can run for a long time and generate a lot of strings.

```
- (NSString *) createGPXFromPositions:(NSArray*)pPositions andHikeName:(NSString*)pHikeName{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    NSString        *dateString;

    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";

    dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    NSString *lText = @"<gpx xmlns=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"1.1\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd\" creator=\"MyApp\">\n\r";
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<trk>\n\r", lText];
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<name>%@</name>\n\r", lText, pHikeName];
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<desc>%@</desc>\n\r", lText, dateString];
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<trkseg>\n\r", lText];

    for (int i=0; i<pPositions.count; i++) {

        EMTrackPoint *lLocation = [pPositions objectAtIndex:i];

        @autoreleasepool {
            lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<trkpt lat=\"%f\" lon=\"%f\">\n\r", lText, lLocation.coordinate.latitude, lLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<ele>%f</ele>\n\r", lText, lLocation.altitude];
            lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<time>%@</time>\n\r", lText, [formatter stringFromDate:lLocation.timestamp]];
            lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<extensions speed=\"%f\"/>\n\r", lText, lLocation.mSpeed];
            lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@</trkpt>\n\r", lText];
        }

    }

    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@</trkseg>\n\r", lText];
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@</trk>\n\r", lText];
    lText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@</gpx>\n\r", lText];

    return lText;
}

}
```

As suggested from this thread I added my autoreleasepool declarations, but this is of no help:
[running out of memory from for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612558/running-out-of-memory-from-for-loop)

I call createGPXFromPositions from inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ }); call:

```
UIApplication * application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {

    //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

//To make the code block asynchronous
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *lGPX = [mTraceRecorder createGPXFromPositions:mTraceRecorder.mUserTrace andHikeName:mHikeInfo.mName];

    //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
    [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
});
```

Yet, after some loops, I get a memory pressure issue, I run into didReceiveMemoryWarning, then my app crashes.

I think that calling stringWithFormat allocates memory, but as I'm using ARC, my strings should be released when not needed anymore, right?
This might be a noob question, but if anyone could help me understand what I did wrong and what best practices I should apply here, I'd be very thankful!

Comment: That's a horrible way to construct a string, from the standpoint of storage use.  Look at NSMutableString.

Comment: Use a mutable string and append to it rather than creating a new string every time.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! Sometimes the solution is so easy that you don't see it at all :/ Is it possible to append a string with format to a NSMutableString? Strings with format are way easier to read.

Comment: `NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString new]; [str appendFormat:@"Format here %@", @"whatever object"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than focusing on the cause of the problem, I focused on its consequences.
As NSString has a stringByAppendingString method, I didn't think of using NSMutableStrings instead. Basic junior developer error, thanks for helping me on that matter Hot Licks, duci9y and Bruno Werminghoff!